# Some Images Disappeared from Media Library?

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I am missing some of my images in my Media Library on my site. When I go and look in the Media Library it shows where the images used to be with a blank thumbnail and if I try to view those images it takes me to a 404 page.

This only happened for a few images and most are still their and viewable, but others are not. I can't seem to figure out what caused these images to do this and what pathways I have to get them back?

If more information is needed I can add it when asked, thanks!

UPDATE: I ran the regenerate thumbnails plugin to see if that would solve it, but when it was running it would give me this message for the broken images:

"Skipped Attachment ID 1676 (R_151023): The fullsize image file cannot be found in your uploads directory at 2015/10/R_151023.jpg. Without it, new thumbnail images can't be generated."

EDIT: I also recently migrated my website to a new hosting provider

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the missing file, which is somewhere in the `wp-content/uploads` folder, was not moved to the new hosting place.

You could use an FTP client to move all images from the old hosting place to your local computer, then use FTP client to copy only the newer images from your local computer to the new hosting place (selecting newer only would be a bit faster than copying everything).

It is also possible that the database entry for that image didn't get updated to the correct URL on the new place. This would be especially if you changed domain names when moving to the new place.

If you have the original copy of the `2015/10/R_151023.jpg` file, you could upload it manually to the `2015/10` folder.